In Snowflake, default value NULL on a not-nullable column?
In Snowflake, what are the implications of having a default value of null on a non-nullable column?
Also, when I describe a particular table in Snowflake, I see a default value of NULL in all columns. When my colleague describes the same table in Snowflake, in the same environment (PROD), they are seeing the default value as null (lower-case) but with all those lower case nulls greyed-out. Anyone out there run into this? What could it mean?

I remember we had a problem with this, data refused to import due to "default value NULL" in Snowflake so we had to change column property in Snowflake in order to proceed with data import

This should take you ~ 20s to test! If you don't receive a similar error message to what you see on the PostgreSQL fiddle, then Snowflake is a bit flaky (please excuse the awful pun :-) ). IMHO, even PostgreSQL shouldn't allow this one to get past the CREATE TABLE stage with such an abomination - maybe a niggle report? This is a breach of the Rule of Repair - "... when you must fail, fail noisily and as soon as possible.".
